# How can I bind variables in a Select statement in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a select statement that is in this form

```
SELECT * 
FROM ?
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = ?
```

How would I bind in this case?

Comment: I can't reproduce - can you add more details like the language used for the second script, and the error that you are seeing? What's the problem?

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(?)
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = ?`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thank you very much and in the binds statement it would look like this? snowflake.execute({sqlText: v_sqlCode1,binds:[value1,value2});?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda for the record - I wrote my question before the question was edited (removing most of it)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Yes, I am aware of it. The original question was ` `TRUNCATE TABLE identifier(?)`;` and I have removed my answer too as it was invalidated by the edit

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake, in addition to identifying objects by name (as detailed in Identifier Requirements), identifiers can also be specified with string literals, session variables, or bind variables, using the IDENTIFIER keyword.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html#string-literals-session-variables-bind-variables-as-identifiers

Example:
Session variables: This shows how to use a session variable that has a table name or schema name:

```
set schema_name = 'my_db.my_schema';
set table_name = 'my_table';
use schema identifier($schema_name);
insert into identifier ($table_name) values (1), (2), (3);
select * from identifier($table_name) order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using the Snowflake Python connector, if so you will see lots of examples at this link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#binding-data

An example from that doc link:

```
con.cursor().execute(
    "INSERT INTO testtable(col1, col2) "
    "VALUES(%s, %s)", (
        789,
        'test string3'
    ))
```

If you are using NodeJS, here is the docs link for that, again with examples.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#binding-statement-parameters

```
connection.execute({
  sqlText: 'select c1 from (select :1 as c1 union all select :2 as c1) where c1 = :1;',
  binds: [1, 2]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [SNOWFLAKE identifier functionality](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal).

For example:

```sql
SET TAB_VAR_01 = 'DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE';
-- SET TAB_VAR_01 = '"DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."VIEW"';  -- or this works too

SET COL_VAR_01 = 'ID';
SET COL_VAR_02 = 'TYPE';

SELECT TOP 100
      identifier($COL_VAR_01) AS TEST_COL
    , identifier($COL_VAR_02) AS TEST_COL2
FROM  identifier($TAB_VAR_01) AS TEST_TABLE;
```